# Make width % based off generated content

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I was wondering if there is a way to make a set width percentage based off the number of posts generated by wordpress.

What I"m trying to do is create a row that will sometimes have 3 or 4 items in it and I would like the to fill up 100% so when there is 4 have each div be 25% but when there are 3 divs have them be 33%.

```
<div class="talent"></div>
<div class="talent"></div>
<div class="talent"></div>

I would give talent a width of 33%, but sometimes it will generate 4 divs

<div class="talent"></div>
<div class="talent"></div>
<div class="talent"></div>
<div class="talent"></div>
```

In which case I would want them to have 25% width, is there a certain way to go about doing this?

Comment: I"m just not sure how to make it set the percentage based upon if 3 divs are generated by wordpress or 4.

Comment: I don;t think you can do this with CSS alone. You might have to use Javascript to count the amount of elements and set the width that way...

Comment: The percentage would be `100 / posts`, is that where you're stuck?

Comment: @Marty No, OP is stuck at conditionally specifying the percentage width of the divs. For example, he wants something like `if number of divs = 4, then width = 25%. If number of divs = 3, then width = 33%` OP knows the percentages, he/she just doesn't know how specify which one to use depending on the number of posts

Comment: @DrydenLong Why would go through that process manually if you could just do `width = 100 / count(posts) %`?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is totally doable. First, you need to count the number of posts generated by the query. Something like:

```
if(have_posts()){
  $num_displayed_posts = ($wp_query->found_posts > get_query_var('posts_per_page')) ? get_query_var('posts_per_page') : $wp_query->found_posts;
  $layout_class = ($num_displayed_posts > 3) ? '4-col' : '3-col';
  //now you can apply this variable to your divs classes
}
```

1. So, count the posts with Wordpress functions
2. generate a variable depending on the number of posts displayed (hence the `get_query_var()`)
3. apply that variable to your div in the loop

Hope that helps. Let me know if you need clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use `display:table` http://fiddle.jshell.net/PJ7e8/1/

```
section {
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;/* will basicly evenly lay cells if no width provided */
    width:100%;
}
section div {
    display:table-cell;
    border:solid;
}
section div:nth-child(odd) {
    background:#cde
}
```

or `display:flex`; http://fiddle.jshell.net/PJ7e8/2/

```
section {
    display:flex;
}
section div {
    flex:1;/* same value for all , width will evenly be dispatch */
    border:solid;
}
section div:nth-child(odd) {
    background:#cde
}
```

HTML used :

```
<section>
    <div class="talent">talent</div>
    <div class="talent">talent</div>
    <div class="talent">talent</div>
</section>
```